# Mean and variance of a vector $W = (X', Y')'$

Tags: self-study, variance, mean, gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

$(X_i,Y_i)$, $i = 1,2, ... ,n$, is a random sample from a bivariate normal distribution, with means $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$, variances $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$, and correlation $\rho$. How do I formally show the mean and variance of a vector $W = (X', Y')'$ where $X$ and $Y$ are vectors as given above?

If I were given $W$'s mean and variance and asked to find $X$ and $Y$'s mean and variance, I could have just taken a vector $[1\ 0]$ and multiplied with $W$ to find $X$ and $Y$. However, how do I proceed when it's the other way round? Can I use the MGF method here? The vectors have been appended and it's not an addition. So I'm not sure MGF would work.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Yes this is from Seber Lee and I was looking at questions for preparing for an exam.

Comment: So please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Yup added. It's not exactly that I'm stuck- the answer seems obvious, i.e. E[W] = [mu_x mu_y]'. I don't know how to go about showing it. Like I mentioned earlier, if it was for X+Y, then I could have used MGF of X+ Y and shown it to be the product of MGF of X and Y. But when two vectors are just appended to each other, I'm not sure how to approach.

Comment: Please explain your notation, because it is ambiguous and not standard: what kind of object is "$(X^\prime,Y^\prime)$" when $X$ and $Y$ are $n$-vectors?  Evidently it's something that can be transposed, and your use of "appended" gives us a hint (but still leaves some ambiguity), but how exactly is it constructed from $X$ and $Y$?